# jQuery.post with MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

I have one problem with `jQuery.post()` syntax.

I have the controller `ExampleController.cs`, with an action:

```
public ActionResult TestPost(Guid fileId) { //do something }
```

and the view `Example.cshtml`, and here I attempt to load this action:

```
function foo(fileGuid) {      
    $.post("Example/TestPost?fileId=" + fileGuid, function () {
        alert("success");
    });
}
```

But there's no alert, I think something wrong with this syntax. Can anyone help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found this way:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("TestPost", "Example")', {fileId : fileGuid} , function () {
        alert("success");
    });
```

and it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the  following 3 callbacks and see if you get an error alert,

```
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
   alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I did as you suggested. I got 2 alerts error and complete, the error was example.php was not found. it's not php btw.

Comment: @QuiTran please accept the answer and close the question from further discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check the Networks option in the console of Chrome and see if there is any error in server side. That can also be a reason why function may have failed.

Comment: I checked it, and it's said POST TestPost?fileId=blahblah 404 Not Found. I suppose that it's failed to load data from server ???

Comment: I think then you should check if you are passing the correct url from the ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a backslash on your location:

```
$.post("/Example...
```

If that does not work, try annotating your method with a post annotation:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestPost(Guid fileId) { //do something }
```

**Edit:**

It is not finding your action because you are specifying the parameter as a Guid. If you change this to a string:

```
 public ActionResult TestPost(string fileId)
 {
       return View();
 }
```

and run:

```
$.post('/Example/TestPost?fileId=123', function () {
  alert('here');
});
```

It should work